# Mate (and Gnome) never goes to suspend

Tags: power-management, 18.10, mate

Ubuntu Mate 18.10 here in a LG Gram 2018 15z980 - Intel Core i7-8550U -iGPU 620 intel

My mate desktop (with compiz) never goes to sleep after the time defined in the power management.
I tried to change to Gnome but the problem persist

It suspends ok when i close the lid

It suspend ok if i use the button or the suspend menu

It suspends ok using different commands like systemctl suspend

It doesn't when the specified time passes. It wakes the screen and just shows the lock screen, Then the cycle begins again. It turns on screensaver, it turns off screen and keyboard and then wakes the screen at the exact time it should go to suspend.

I saw some related cases but mostly about turning off the screen (which is not my problem)

I already tried to change the window management to marco and compton to test if it were something related with compiz.
The only error i saw in the logs is

```
(mate-power-manager:10541): GLib-CRITICAL **: 11:47:59.224: Source ID 2201 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your hardware?

Comment: LG Gram 2018 15z980 - Intel Core i7-8550U -iGPU 620 intel . but as i said suspend works ok, but it doesn't by the PM timer

Comment: Well, that does sound a bit weird then. As a result, part of me wants to ask this question then: did you verify the Ubuntu Mate .iso file you downloaded before sticking it on a USB or disc and installing it on your LG Gram?

Comment: As a matter of fact.. no, I didn't. I have some free space left in the sdd so i could reinstall a try to reproduce the problem. But.. everything else works and every other PM timer works (screen, screensaver, etc)

Comment: Well corruption could've happened and have affected anything on the system, even something as trivial as the PM features. I suppose that have you updated your system too?

Comment: yes, i did update everything, even the kernel to the latest 5.0 to try in case it was something ACPI related but .. suspend works . is just the Timer that instead of suspending brings back the lock screen

Comment: Well, maybe if the PM features were the only corrupted part, then you shouldn't have a problem, and if apt was corrupted, you would probably had more issues than just PM...  I guess I would still try a clean side-install to be sure, and maybe see if it's working before and after updates. I recommend installing without any use of the internet though, and then doing your update via the information [here](https://justi.cz/security/2019/01/22/apt-rce.html), as there is a recent apt vulnerability.

Comment: And yeah, I wonder if PM breaks during an update, or if its broken out of the box and still broken after updates.

Comment: One other thing I may suggest is reinstall ubuntu-mate-desktop, a metapackage ( a package that queues in installation of a series of packages), to be sure to see if the PM packages are installed at all as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90670/discussion-between-carlinux-and-roundduckman).